# jacocoTestReport not being generated on Jenkins

Tags: android, jenkins, sonarqube, build.gradle, jacoco

I am working on the SonarQube code coverage...I have implemented locally and able to see jacocoTestReprt and all other necessary files...but when I run the task on Jenkins jacoco not able to generate any files.

In app/build.gradle

> task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn:
> [‘testProdReleaseUnitTest’]) {
>
> reports {
> xml.enabled = true
> html.enabled = true }
>
> def fileFilter = ['**/R.class', '**/R$*.class', '**/BuildConfig.*',
> '**/Manifest*.*', 'android/**/*.*'] def debugTree = fileTree(dir:
> "${buildDir}/intermediates/javac/prodRelease/classes", excludes:
> fileFilter) def mainSrc = "${project.projectDir}/src/main/java"
>
> getSourceDirectories().setFrom(files([mainSrc]))
> getClassDirectories().setFrom(files([debugTree]))
> getExecutionData().setFrom(fileTree(dir: "$buildDir", includes:
> ["jacoco/testProdReleaseUnitTest.exec"])
> }

Jenkins artifacts:
[image]

Comment: can you share jenkins logs?

Comment: Even I am facing the same issue with the maven plugin. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67524321/code-coverage-and-reports-not-generating-on-sonarqube-for-java-using-maven-and-j